# Gradle property flag is not working for Maven plugin when uploadArchives task is called

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm using the maven plugin to upload my library to a repo but I can't seem to get the property flag for gradle to work. Here's what I call from the command line

`.\gradlew.bat uploadArchives -PRELEASE=true`

and here is what I have to test that the property flag is working

```
uploadArchives {

    def isReleaseBuild = hasProperty("RELEASE") && RELEASE == true;
    if (isReleaseBuild) {
        println "Release Build"
    } else {
        println "Snapshot Build"
    }
}
```

This prints out "Snapshot Build" every time rather than "Release Build". Any thoughts as to why `isReleaseBuild` is false?

Answer (score 1):

So there was 2 things wrong with the my gradle script. I needed to use `project.hasProperty()` otherwise the return value was null and input parameters are parsed as strings so my comparison needed to be `RELEASE == "true"`